# See all graph outputs from loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 20 variables in a dataframe (i.e. data) from which I would like to have histograms, boxplots and some other graphs (for clarity I have provided an example of just a boxplot). I would like to sort these outcomes by the variable 'Group'. I have tried solving this with a loop, so that each variable (column) is translated into a graph. (I know loops are not favored by Stackoverflow programmers and I welcome all other solutions). On the y axis I would like to print the name of each of 20 variables.

```
for (i in 1:20)  { 
    graph <- ggplot(data, aes(Group,data[,i])) 
    print(graph + geom_boxplot() + labs(x = "Group", y = VariableName[i]) + 
    theme_classic())
}
```

The output results in only the last graph, which seems logical as the loop overwrites the output. It does not matter to me whether the output is saved in separate files or whether I can view it in separate windows, as long as I can observe the output for each variable.

Comment: Have you looked into `ggsave`? Something like `ggsave(filename=paste(i,".jpg", sep=""), plot=graph)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lapply` instead, to create a list of plots. No reproducible example, but something like this should work:

```
graphs <- lapply(1:20, function(i) {
  ggplot(data, aes(Group, data[,i])) + geom_boxplot() + 
    labs(x = "Group", y = VariableName[i]) + 
    theme_classic())
}
```

You can access each graph with `graphs[[index]]`.